# Array to string conversion error PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

```
array(2) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#460 (1) { ["deskripsi"]=> string(14) "Embedded teeth" }
[1]=> object(stdClass)#461 (1) { ["deskripsi"]=> string(14) "Impacted teeth" } 
}
```

That is my array result after I `vardump` from database query.
Then I want to get text **Embedded teeth** and **Impacted teeth**

Can someone please help me?

Comment: post your code how you tried to get Embedded teeth and Impacted teeth value

Comment: Where's the error? That's just some output followed by you asking how to get a value. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array of objects, the code below should help point you in the right direction

```
$objects = $myObj;
foreach($objects as $object){
    echo $object->deskripsi;
}
```